# Indented Text to array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to format some indendet email-text into an array.
My current solution works fine until a field occurs multiple times.
In that case I only get the last occured value.

Here an example mail:

```
auftragstyp:
    geschaeftsfall: NEU
    aenderungsKennzeichen: Standard
    geschaeftsfallart: Bereitstellung
meldungstyp:
    meldungsattribute:
        externeAuftragsnummer: testvalue
        kundennummer: testnumber
        verbindlicherLiefertermin: 2021-06-22
        produktpositionen:
            position:
                aktionscode: Z
                produkt:
                    bezeichner: TAL; CuDA 2 Draht hbr (HVt)
                    uebertragungsVerfahren: H16
            position:
                aktionscode: Z
                produkt:
                    bezeichner: TAL; Neuschaltung mArb.Ek./mArb.KVz
        vertragsnummer: testvalue
        leitung:
            leitungsbezeichnung:
                leitungsschluesselzahl: 96W
                onkzA: 7243
                onkzB: 7243
                ordnungsnummer: 123456678
            leitungsabschnitt:  <-- problematic
                LfdNrLeitungsabschnitt: 1
                Leitungslaenge: 1399
                Leitungsdurchmesser: 400
            leitungsabschnitt:  <-- problematic
                LfdNrLeitungsabschnitt: 2
                Leitungslaenge: 183
                Leitungsdurchmesser: 600
            maxBruttoBitrate: 4308
        schaltangaben:
```

As you can see the field "leitungsabschnitt" and its values occurrs twice.

After running the function my array-keys look like this:

```
...
meldungstyp.meldungsattribute.leitung.leitungsbezeichnung
meldungstyp.meldungsattribute.leitung.leitungsbezeichnung.leitungsschluesselzahl
meldungstyp.meldungsattribute.leitung.leitungsbezeichnung.onkzA
meldungstyp.meldungsattribute.leitung.leitungsbezeichnung.onkzB
meldungstyp.meldungsattribute.leitung.leitungsbezeichnung.ordnungsnummer
meldungstyp.meldungsattribute.leitung.leitungsabschnitt
meldungstyp.meldungsattribute.leitung.leitungsabschnitt.LfdNrLeitungsabschnitt
meldungstyp.meldungsattribute.leitung.leitungsabschnitt.Leitungslaenge
meldungstyp.meldungsattribute.leitung.leitungsabschnitt.Leitungsdurchmesser
...
```

My current coding attempt is:

```
function indent2array($text, $indentation = '    ', $delimiter = '.')
{
    $array  = explode("\r\n", $text);
    $return = [];
    $levels = [];

    foreach ($array as $line) {
        $line           = explode(':', $line);
        $lineKey        = array_shift($line);
        $level          = count(explode($indentation, $lineKey)) - 1;
        $levels[$level] = trim($lineKey);
        $key            = implode($delimiter, array_chunk($levels, $level + 1)[0]);
        $return[$key]   = trim(implode(":", $line));
    }

    return $return;
}
```

I think I have to convert the value into an array and append the new value if the field already exists.

With the correct code the resulting array-keys should be:

```
...
meldungstyp.meldungsattribute.leitung.leitungsabschnitt.0.LfdNrLeitungsabschnitt
meldungstyp.meldungsattribute.leitung.leitungsabschnitt.0.Leitungslaenge
meldungstyp.meldungsattribute.leitung.leitungsabschnitt.0.Leitungsdurchmesser
meldungstyp.meldungsattribute.leitung.leitungsabschnitt.1.LfdNrLeitungsabschnitt
meldungstyp.meldungsattribute.leitung.leitungsabschnitt.1.Leitungslaenge
meldungstyp.meldungsattribute.leitung.leitungsabschnitt.1.Leitungsdurchmesser
...
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can realise this?
I thought of recursion but this gives me a bit of a headache :-/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which also suits my needs, but it's a bit different result:

```
function indent2array($text, $indentation = '    ', $delimiter = '.')
{
    $lines  = explode("\r\n", $text);
    $return = [];
    $levels = [];
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $line           = explode(':', $line);
        $lineKey        = array_shift($line);
        $level          = count(explode($indentation, $lineKey)) - 1;
        $levels[$level] = trim($lineKey);
        $key            = implode($delimiter, array_chunk($levels, $level + 1)[0]);
        $value          = trim(implode(":", $line));
        if (!isset($return[$key])) {
            if (!is_null($value) && $value !== '') {
                $return[$key] = $value;
            }
            continue;
        }
        if (!is_array($return[$key])) {
            $return[$key] = [$return[$key]];
        }
        $return[$key][] = $value;
    }

    return $return;
}
```

The result looks like this now:

```
...
    [meldungstyp.meldungsattribute.leitung.leitungsbezeichnung.ordnungsnummer] => FXP00J3YI6
    [meldungstyp.meldungsattribute.leitung.leitungsabschnitt.LfdNrLeitungsabschnitt.0] => 1
    [meldungstyp.meldungsattribute.leitung.leitungsabschnitt.LfdNrLeitungsabschnitt.1] => 2
    [meldungstyp.meldungsattribute.leitung.leitungsabschnitt.Leitungslaenge.0] => 1399
    [meldungstyp.meldungsattribute.leitung.leitungsabschnitt.Leitungslaenge.1] => 183
    [meldungstyp.meldungsattribute.leitung.leitungsabschnitt.Leitungsdurchmesser.0] => 400
    [meldungstyp.meldungsattribute.leitung.leitungsabschnitt.Leitungsdurchmesser.1] => 600
    [meldungstyp.meldungsattribute.leitung.maxBruttoBitrate] => 4308
...
```

As you can see, the numerical index is appended instead of prepended to last field-name.